# How do I connect to StackExchange Redis in C# Application

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I pulled and ran a Docker image
`docker run --name notepad-dev-redis -d redis` and I am able to verify it is up and running. I have went into it and executed a few commands to verify this.

I am trying to connect to this running instance via my C# Web Api (.NET 6).

I've wired everything up correctly but I am getting this error:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: The timeout was reached before the message could be written 
to the output buffer, and it was not sent, command=HMGET, timeout: 5000, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 0, aw: False, 
bw: CheckingForTimeout, serverEndpoint: localhost:6379, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, 
clientName: b6d2ea18a5aa(SE.Redis-v2.6.66.47313), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=16,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=16,Max=32767), 
POOL: (Threads=11,QueuedItems=0,CompletedItems=291), v: 2.6.66.47313 
(Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

I've looked around at numerous articles and haven't come up with anything.

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options => {
                options.Configuration = configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis");
                options.InstanceName = "Notepad_";
            });
```

MyService.cs
(I've tried multiple implementations)

(1) DI

(2) Lazy

(Implementation #1 - DI)

```
private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

public MyService(IDistributedCache distributedCache){
    _distributedCache = distributedCache;
}

public void DoWork(){
    _distributedCache.GetStringAsync("myKey"); // throws error
}
```

(Implementation #2 - Lazy<>)

```
private Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> _lazyConnection;
private IDatabase _cache = null;

public MyService(){
    _lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
            {
                string cacheConnection = $"{_configuration.GetConnectionString("Redis")},ssl=true,abortConnect=false,allowAdmin=True,connectRetry=5";
                return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(cacheConnection);
            });
}

public void DoWork(){
    _cache = _lazyConnection.Value.GetDatabase();
    _cache.StringGetAsync("myKey"); // throws error
}
```

Comment: What is your connection string?  Have you tried to access it from outside the container using a Redis manager?

Comment: yes, I am able to connect using the redis-cli. My connection string is localhost:6379

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't expose your container port.
try to using telnet to ensure that it is exposed correctly

cmd >> `telnet localhost 6379`

If you understand that your container port didn't expose, change your docker run command as follows:

```
docker run -p 6379:6379 --name notepad-dev-redis -d redis
```